# WebpackError: useMantineColorScheme hook was called outside of context

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin, mantine

I'm using gatsby js and the mantine library. Everything works fine when I run yarn develop, but when I try yarn build I get this error:

```
 WebpackError: useMantineColorScheme hook was called outside of context, make sure your app is wrapped with ColorSchemeProvider component (from plu
  gin: gatsby-plugin-mantine)
```

I've followed this exactly: https://mantine.dev/theming/dark-theme/

My package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@js-temporal/polyfill": "^0.4.1",
    "@mantine/core": "^4.2.9",
    "@mantine/hooks": "^4.2.9",
    "gatsby": "^4.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.14.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^4.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-mantine": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^5.14.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.14.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.14.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.14.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.14.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "tabler-icons-react": "^1.49.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16",
    "@types/react": "^16",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.24.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.24.0",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{ts,tsx,json}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
```